# How do you define a variadic function in a Chicken Scheme module?

Tags: function, module, variadic-functions, chicken-scheme

Is this a bug in Chicken Scheme?

```
#;1> (define (foo x . y) x)
#;2> (foo 1 2 3)
1
#;3> (module bar (import scheme chicken) (define (foo x . y) x))

Error: invalid syntax in macro form: (foo x . y)

        Call history:

        <syntax>                (module bar (import scheme chicken) (define (foo x . y) x))
        <syntax>                (##core#module bar (import scheme chicken) (define (foo x . y) x))
        <syntax>                (define (foo x . y) x)
        <syntax>                (foo x . y)     <--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot (`.`) syntax for variadic functions is not available across modules; it's inside the `scheme` module. When you create a custom module, you have to explicitly import the `scheme` module to reenable variadic functions.

```
#1;> (module bar (foo) (import scheme chicken) (define (foo x . y) x))
#2;> (import bar)
#3;> (foo 1 2 3)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your module syntax is missing the list of symbols to export from the module.  Try this:

```
#1;> (module bar (foo) (import scheme chicken) (define (foo x . y) x))
#2;> (import bar)
#3;> (foo 1 2 3)
1
```

Notice the (foo) after declaring the module name.

I'll add that the [mailing list](https://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/chicken-users) and irc channel (#chicken on freenode) are very active.  If you have questions about chicken they are the best places to get them answered.